# django query to filter and distinct

Tags: database, django, django-models

I have a table as follows:

table_name : example

```
values
1
1
2

2
3

3
```

the value list contains the values as above. When i write a distinct query on the able table, i get 1 2 3 and a empty '' value.

I want to get rid of the `null` value as it is posing some problems in my program.
the query for that which i have written is:

```
example.objects.values_list('values',flat = True).distinct()
```

Is there a a way to filter out that empty value

Comment: Sorry, voted down by mistake, can't unvote until the question is edited...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
example.objects.exclude(
      Q(values__isnull=True)|Q(values='')
    ).values_list('values', flat=True).distinct()
```

Answer (score 3):

As other answers mentioned, if you have a `null`/`empty string` confusion. You might exclude both using complex lookup parameters like:

```
from django.db.models import Q
example.objects.exclude(Q(values__isnull=True)|Q(values='')).values_list('values',flat = True).distinct()
```

[Complex Lookups are here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)...

Comment: You have to use the | between the Q's not within.

Comment: @FallenAngel: The code works now. But if i get a syntax error if i use both the values_isnull and values. But when i used only the values = '' the null values were not displayed.Thank you for your help

Comment: @sankar i fixed my typo, you can use it now

Comment: Sorry, i make a mistake in Q usage, it is fixed now, Thank you @AndreBossard

Answer (score 1):

You can try filtering out the null values first and then chain your filter, as below

```
example.objects.exclude(values=None).values_list('values',flat = True).distinct()
```

Comment: If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the flat parameter. If True, this will mean the returned results are single values, rather than one-tuples. An example should make the difference clearer (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Comment: i tried this code, but still i am getting null values in my list

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`is_null`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) field lookup:

```
example.objects.filter(values__isnull=False).values_list('values',flat = True).distinct()
```

So query string before `.values_list(...` will return all records from `example` table, which `values` field is not null.

As *@BurhanKhalid* has noticed, this attempt will work only if your `values` field is NULL-able

Comment: This is a good idea but it would only work if the field is `NULL`-able; but from the output it seems the field has a default value of `""` (an empty string).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it's true. My answer based on that assumption

Comment: i have tried this code, but it does not seem to work. i still get a list with null values